# Making dropdown visible javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor, umbraco

I made a dropdown system with razor script in Umbraco. I finally got all the children working but how do I hide the sub items that should be a dropdown list? I tried something with javascript but that seemed to open all dropdowns instead of each one individually.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <div class="well well-lg span-padding extra-padding top background-light">
    <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
      @ {
        var documentRootNodeId = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("documentRoot", true); // Fetch recursive document root id.
        var selection = Umbraco.TypedContent(documentRootNodeId).Children.Where("Visible"); // Select all nodes below the document root.
      }
      @foreach(var item in Model.Content.Ancestor(1).Descendants("menu")) {
        foreach(var ItemChild in @item.Children("hoofdstuk")) { 
        <li> @ItemChild.Name </li>
          foreach(var Subitem in @ItemChild.Children) { 
          <li><a href = "@Subitem.Url"> @Subitem.Name </a></li>
              if (Subitem.Children.Any()) {
                foreach(var Finalitem in @Subitem.Children) { 
                  <ul>
                    <li> < a href = "@Finalitem.Url" > @Finalitem.Name </a></li>
                  </ul>
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function myFunction(a) {
    var itemcount = a.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("sub").length;
    for (i = 0; i < itemcount; i++) { 
        a.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("sub")[i].classList.toggle("show");
    }
}
```

This is what it displays:

[image]

Sub-Subtest1 and 2 needs to be hidden till we click it's ancestor which is SubTest1. Same goes for sub-subtest9.

I can't seem to get it working dynamically. If I create something with javascript it opens all the dropdown's at once and not individually.

Comment: First provide us with your javascript, second I would advise you to use classes, and id's so that you can target the individual elements. Thanks!

Comment: I removed the javascript from the code as it wasn't working the way I wanted to. I added a class to the ul and used javascript to change the display. I'll add the javascript code anyway and adjust the html code so it uses the javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would recommend you to use Visual Studio, that will help you to fix issues with your code. You should fix your html structure and nest the elements of your list properly. You have `li` as direct children of `li` which is invalid.

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="well well-lg span-padding extra-padding top background-light">
        <ul class="nav nav-list tree">
            @{
                var documentRootNodeId = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("documentRoot", true); // Fetch recursive document root id.
                var selection = Umbraco.TypedContent(documentRootNodeId).Children.Where("Visible"); // Select all nodes below the document root.
            }
            @foreach (var item in Model.Content.Ancestor(1).Descendants("menu"))
            {
                foreach (var ItemChild in item.Children("hoofdstuk"))
                {
                    <li class="item">
                        @if (ItemChild.Children.Any())
                        {
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                @foreach (var Subitem in ItemChild.Children)
                                {
                                    <li class="item">
                                        <a href="@Subitem.Url"> @Subitem.Name </a>
                                        @if (Subitem.Children.Any())
                                         {
                                            foreach (var Finalitem in Subitem.Children)
                                            {
                                                <ul class="submenu">
                                                    <li> <a href="@Finalitem.Url"> @Finalitem.Name </a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </li>

                                }
                            </ul>
                        }
                    </li>
                }
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can use jQuery to easily show the submenus. Use `[children][1]` to retrieve only the first level of submenus:

```
$(".item").click(function(){
    $(this).children(".submenu").toggle(); //it will display or hide your submenu when clicking the item.
});
```

And your submenu should be hidden by default, you can do that with css:

```
.submenu{
    display: none;
}
```

**Note**: to make the code more clear I would recommend you to use Razor helpers to create a recursive function for your sublists.

Comment: I wish I could use visual studio but I can't, I do not have access to the server where the site is hosted on. The code seems to be working but the entire navigation bar vanishes. I'll check if I can fix that and apply your changes.

Comment: I managed to get it working with a few tweaks to your code! Thank you!

Comment: Hey, the only problem that I have now is that I have to open the dropdown menu again once I navigate to one of the dropdown pages, how do I fix that?

Comment: That's a different issue. When you navigate to a new page you have to include the right logic to detect which item in the list is the current one and apply a class to keep it open. Try with IPublishedContent.AncestorOrSelf() extension method.